# Adding certificate in userSMIMECertificate attribute of inetOrgPerson

Tags: ldap, x509certificate, smime, ldif, adlds

I'm going to publish a certificate for my email using LDAP.
I already have a LDAP up and running (AD LDS) on windows 2012.
I'm going to add records using ldif file.

Here its contents

```
dc: dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com

dn: dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: mydomain
dc: mysubdomain
description: Some root stuff

dn: ou=mysubdomaincertificates,dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: mysubdomaincertificates

dn: Mail=test@mysubdomain.mydomain.com,ou=mysubdomaincertificates,dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Test Test
sn: Test
Mail: test@mysubdomain.mydomain.com
userSMIMECertificate: #<What to put?>
```

I'm stuck in compiling my ldif file. As I understand, I need to put some binary encoded in Base64 with some prefix {CERT} or something.

My questions are

1. Will this ldif file make modifications into the directory?
2. Do I have problems except `userSMIMECertificate` field?

   - For example I'm using dc twice in the domain object, is it ok?
   - Am I missing some other important line?
3. What is exact syntax of putting certificate content in the `userSMIMECertificate`? (I've made a search, but could not find the examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your LDIF with the appropriate changes:

```
dn: dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: mysubdomain
description: Some root stuff

dn: ou=mysubdomaincertificates,dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: mysubdomaincertificates
description: Provide some descriptive text here.

dn: Mail=test@mysubdomain.mydomain.com,ou=mysubdomaincertificates,dc=mysubdomain,dc=mydomain,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Test Test
sn: Test
Mail: test@mysubdomain.mydomain.com
userSMIMECertificate: file:///path-cert-file
```

Comment: Thank you Terry. Your answer covers all my questions.

Comment: Note that it's actually not correct to store the certificate in `userSMIMECertificate`. Instead, it should be stored in `userCertificate`. [As explained here](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-devel/199904/msg00037.html), `userSMIMECertificate` was designed to hold an empty (zero byte) S/MIME message signed with the certificate which gives the option to include the certificate chain as well the algorithm capabilities and preferences of the email client.

Answer (score 0):

*As a useful supplement to the existing answer from Terry Gardner*

To avoid that your ldif depends on an external file, you might want to specify the userSMIMECertificate in such a way:

```
userSMIMECertificate:: Q29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogYXR0YWNobWVudDsKCWZpbGVuY
 W1lPXNtaW1lLnA3cwpDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3BrY3M3LXNpZ25hdHVyZTsK
[...]
```

This is basically the base64-encoded file contents.

In order to get rid of file dependencies, it's easiest to import the ldif with the file dependencies, then export the object to a new ldif. The export should create above format.